# Master Detail Page - show menu icon in Android

Tags: c#, android, navigation, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I created app with Xamarin Forms for ANdroid. I use Master Detail Page. It is my code:

```
public Master ()
{

    Master = new MenuPage ();

    root = new Root ();
    var navigation = new NavigationPage (root);

    Detail = navigation;
    this.IsPresented = false;
}
```

It is my navigation(I need a history navigation):

```
 await navigation.PushAsync (new MyPage());
```

I am get back button in Android (when go new page).  I'v tried to hide the back button using it

```
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton (this, false);
```

but the menu icon is not visible anyways. But the menu is accessible by swiping from the left edge, so the menu is there, but I need the icon.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you don't want a back button and want the menu item to be constantly visible? You just need to replace your detail page with your new page

```
Detail = new NavigationPage(new MyPage());
```

Comment: I need a history navigation. This does not work with history.